# Program to read shortcut (.lnk) files and modify its properties

Tags: windows, gratis, open-source, file-management, windows-10

I would like a GUI program capable to open/read a shortcut file and modify all of its properties, with total ease (like for example showing the original values in a editable textbox, and a button to save any changes made, preferably with some kind of good error-handling for syntax error and/or non-existent paths).

Requisites:

- It must be a standalone program with a graphical user-interface. Not a command-line application.
- The program must be focused to perform this task, preferably having a functionality implemented to drag shortcuts to the program's window. Avoid hexadecimal programs.
- The program can run under Windows 10 x64.
- The program can modify EVERY property of a shortcut file, including target file path, working directory and icon file (and icon index).
- Freeware. But paid alternatives are welcome to discuss.

Please note that there is nothing useful in this article:

- [6 Free Tools To Analyze Windows LNK Shortcut Files](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/parse-and-analyze-windows-lnk-shortcut-files/)

Comment: What's unsatisfactory about the built-in handling (i.e., right-click on the icon, select PROPERTIES)?

Comment: @Jeff Zeitlin The built-in feature does not show some relevant info, like the index of the icon selected. Also I prefer just to have opened a program and drop there shortcut by shortcut to make modifications. Thanks for comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of looking for perfection, I decided to develop by myself what I consider perfect for my needs.

Then finally I finished the initial release of **Easy Link File Viewer**, a simple, friendly, open-source shortcut file viewer and editor:

[image]

[image]

[image]

### List of current features:

- Portable application. No installation is needed, and no post-configuration is needed.
- Supports multiple program instances. You can open and edit various files at once this way.
- Friendly file editor.
- File Drag&Drop.
- Visual Theming.
- List with Most Recent Used (MRU) shortcut files.
- Can read shortcuts with special (virtual) targets.
- Apply changes directly to the current shortcut file, or save a copy of it to another destination.

### Download:

[image: https://github.com/ElektroStudios/Easy-Link-File-Viewer/releases/latest]

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer as a Library is not a standalone application. But [this library called ShellLink](https://github.com/securifybv/ShellLink) appears to be able to read and edit .lnk files. It would be trivial to build a GUI around this library however. You can also try the application talked about in [this thread](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/151752-lnkeditorgui-windows-shortcut-lnk-link-editor-gui/), however it's really hard to know how it works, what it looks like an if you can trust it so I would not bother unless you find it very important to try.

Comment: First of all, thanks for answer. I think it's time to clarify some important things. In firs t point, I'm aware of the IShellLink native interface to create, modify, and resolve shortcut links. In fact, I'm a software developer and I have a shortcut file parser implemented for a commercial library (not for a GUI), but I have less and less time to dedicate to programming and to this, to design a GUI and use my library and do all the error-handling and unit testing. It's not laziness, just I found a better/faster option asking for a GUI program that is already made to accomplish this task.

Comment: In second point, the application that you linked is not a standalone application, it's an script made in Auto-It that would need the interpreter to be ran. That will mean undesired dependencies. I appreciate your interest in trying to help, but I only would accept a GUI program.

Comment: @ElektroStudios I totally understand, I was just as intrigued by your question as yourself so I did some googling and this was the only thing I could find, hence the "partial answer" opening. I wish you the best of luck to look for a good tool. If I have some spare time, I will code one myself

Comment: Because I feel that I'm not going to be able discover a standalone program for this, I started developing my own tool: https://i.imgur.com/iLJRB2r.png - that was made in some minutes but would require many time to finish and implement the "editable" part (to apply the shortcut file modifications). I will publish it in GitHub and share it in this thread some day. Thanks again for your help/answer.